# Complex blade file names don't resolve

Tags: php, laravel, template-engine, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

So I am trying to include some partials into a form page, but I have used more complex file names than what may be typical. For example, I have a form as follows:

```
@extends('shared.app')

@section('content')

    <h2>Search page</h2>
    <p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>

    <hr/>

    @include('main.partials.forms.search.form')

@stop
```

However I get an error like: 
**ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View    [main.partials.forms.search.form] not found. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp/resources/views/main/search.blade.php)**

As you may have guessed I'm trying to include a blade file under a folder views/main/partials/forms/  the file name is: search.form.blade.php

I am thinking that by the nature of how the blade engine finds its files, this isn't possible to do (even though I'd like to use this naming convention). Just in case, I wanted to know if anyone came up with any solutions to this.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, my current "workaround" is to change the filenames to things like search_form.blade.php

Comment: It's not bug. See the Laravel's code for accessing view files. It explodes the path with '.' and follows the path until the (lets say) `$path[count($path)-2]` and finally reaches for `"{$path[count($path)-1]}.blade.php"` file. That's why it assumes that 'search' is a folder.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was guessing it would do, appreciate the check!